# How do I get value from ValuesView? Trying to make sense of Dialogflow response for my bot

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a bot using DialogFlow, Twilio and Flask but I'm currently stuck at something that show seem easy but couldn't find a lot of answers.

Basically I fetch de json answer from Dialogflow using the function below:

```
def fetch_reply(query, session_id):
    #gets response from DialogFlow
    response = detect_intent_from_text(query, session_id)
    resp = {}
    #Understading response and seeting it to a dictionary
    print(response)
    resp['text']=response.fulfillment_text
    resp['intent']=response.intent.display_name
    resp['parameters'] = response.parameters.fields.values()
    return resp
```

I printed the full response, and it gives me the following:

```
query_text: "Tim\303\243o"
parameters {
  fields {
    key: "soccerteams"
    value {
      string_value: "Corinthians"
    }
  }
}
all_required_params_present: true
fulfillment_messages {
  text {
    text: ""
  }
}
intent {
  name: "projects/whatsappbotsports-ylml/agent/intents/e7bcf0f5-d37f-4c8b-81ad-09579fded36a"
  display_name: "Default Team Request"
}
intent_detection_confidence: 1.0
language_code: "pt-br"
```

but when I print the resp['parameter'] my result is:

```
ValuesView({'soccerteams': string_value: "Corinthians"
})
```

All I need to access is "Corinthians", or the value of string_value, but I can't find a way to do it. If I try to use resp['parameter'].value or resp['parameter'].string_value it gives me that ValuesView doesn't have this attributes.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's some very strange output that you have. It's not a JSON, since the keys don't have quotes around them.

Can you try something like this?

```
import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

def fetch_reply(query, session_id):
    #gets response from DialogFlow
    response = detect_intent_from_text(query, session_id)
    # trying to parse json
    soccerteams = response.parameters.fields["soccerteams"]
    soccerteams_json = json.loads(MessageToJson(soccerteams))
    return soccerteams_json
```

and then try to get the value from json.

That's just my try to adapt this code: [Get Dialogflow context parameters from a follow up intent in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477270/get-dialogflow-context-parameters-from-a-follow-up-intent-in-python)

Let me know if it worked. If not, please send some output.

Comment: It did works! Thank you so much for the help. I just did it on all parameters and the result is a dictionary, super helpful!